# Jackson: custom deserializer: cannot deserialize XML with array

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, deserialization

I use Jackson to serialize one of my classes as XML.
Because of the complex internal structure, I use a custom serializer that generates this data as an array.

The resulting XML looks like this in a simplified example:

```
<MyDataType>
    <list>
        <entry>
            <order>0</order>
            <value>And then a step to the right</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <order>1</order>
            <value>It's just a jump to the left</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <order>2</order>
            <value>With your hands on your hips</value>
        </entry>
    </list>
</MyDataType>
```

I only get problems when I deserialize.
Then `jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser)` just "sees" the last entry of the array. All other entries are lost.

So the debug output in the deserializer will show:

```
Deserialize: Incoming data:
{
    "list": {
        "entry": {
            "order": "2",
            "value": "With your hands on your hips"
        }
    }
}
```

Even more weird: If I serialize/deserialize to JSON, the *same* code works fine!

Deserializer:

```
class MyDataTypeDeserialize extends JsonDeserializer<MyDataType> {
    @Override
    public MyDataType deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        MyDataType result = new MyDataType();

        JsonNode rootNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);

        // Shows only one entry when using XML
        System.out.println("Deserialize: Incoming data: " + rootNode.toString());

        JsonNode valueList = rootNode.get("list");
        JsonNode entryList = valueList.findValue("entry");

        for (Iterator<JsonNode> it = entryList.elements(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            JsonNode element = it.next();

            int order = element.get("order").asInt();
            String value = element.get("value").asText();

            result.addValue(order, value);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Any hints what I'm doing wrong will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/36484953/1776132 ?

Answer (score 0):

**[Edited]**

I ran into the same issue a couple of years back.
By default Jackson (most specifically the UntypedObjectDeserializer) when sees multiple children with the same name it does not map them into an array or list.
What I did is I used this library: https://search.maven.org/classic/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.json%22%20AND%20a%3A%22json%22
With that you can do:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(...);
String jsonText = jsonObject.toString();
// Use Jackson here
```

Of course this is an additional parsing and then serialization step before you can actually deserialize as a Jackson node.
The above worked fine for me, because it wasn't on the critical path of the application.

**[Edit]**

In your case where you need to use JsonParser in a deserializer you could try something like this:

```
JsonLocation start = jp.getCurrentLocation();
jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser); // The result is ignored
JsonLocation end = jp.getCurrentLocation();

String xmlText = end.getSourceRef().toString().substring(start.getCharOffset() - 1, end.getCharOffset());

JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xmlText);
String jsonText = jsonObject.toString();

// Parse jsonText into JsonNode
```

Or an alternative solution: https://github.com/DinoChiesa/deserialize-xml-arrays-jackson/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/xmldeser/ArrayInferringUntypedObjectDeserializer.java

Comment: dfritsi, thank you for your effort, however, your suggestion is not quite feasable for me. Alone because sourceRef in my case is a StringReader and therefore "end.getSourceRef().toString()" returns "java.io.StringReader@xxxxxxxx" and not any xml text.

Another reason is, that it is not up to me to introduce further libraries for parsing JSON/XML as this is a larger company project. I have to cope with Jackson alone I'm afraid.

Comment: I know the feeling. Would it be a solution to correctly annotate the MyDataType class and then simply do: return jsonParser.getCodec().readValue(jsonParser, MyDataType.cass); ? If not, I would create an interim classes like: https://pastebin.com/DJDXtJrd Haven't tested this, you might have to play around with the annotations, but this is what I'd do.

Comment: Sorry, but if I could do that, I would not have needed my own deserializer at all. But if this is not a bug in Jackson, it seems so, that I will need some interims classes that could be serialized the standard way, using annotations.

Comment: Well, if you cannot modify the original POJOs and it you don't want to create interim classes, then you can use the JsonParser instance as a SAX parser. So instead of reading the next object as a whole JsonNode (DOM parsing) and then iterating the JsonNode instance you could do something similar which is in the question part of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612006/jackson-sax-parser-throws-exception-when-parsing-huge-json